# How to replace text from <b> with regex and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regular-language

This is an html part I'd like to parse:

```
<b id="finish_kar_cri">0x61496a395F549XzxzxZ</b>
```

How can I replace this part:

```
0x61496a395F549XzxzxZ
```

to

```
8472875
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $('#finish_kar_cri').html='8472875'

Comment: Not enough jQuery `document.getElementById("finish_kar_cri").innerText = "*****";`

Comment: explain why you want to use a regex?

Comment: or for straight dom, you could do window.document.getElementById('finish_kar_cri').innerHTML = '8472875';

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change() {
  var myelem = $('#finish_kar_cri');
  myelem.text('8472875');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b id="finish_kar_cri">0x61496a395F549XzxzxZ</b>
<button onclick='change()'>Change Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change(){
    document.getElementById("finish_kar_cri").innerHTML = "8472875";
}
```

```html
<b id="finish_kar_cri">0x61496a395F549XzxzxZ</b>
<button onclick='change()'>Change Text</button>
```